# Testing Bag as parameter...

Tags: java, parameters, bag

I would like to test the method below in the interactions pane, but do not know how to create the "Bag other" in the parameter of the method so that I can check whether this method works or not.

```
public class ArrayBag implements Bag {

 public boolean removeItems(Bag other) {
    if(other == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("other cannot be null"); 
    } 
    if(other.numItems() == 0){
        return false; 
    }
    //make bag into array 
    Object[] otherArr = other.toArray(); 

    //remove all occurences of item 
    int check = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < otherArr.length; i++){
        if(remove(otherArr[i])){
            i--; 
            check++; 
        }
    }

    //return value 
    if(check > 0){
        return true; 
    }else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your ArrayBag class is an implementation of Bag. So create another instance of ArrayBag. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the whole bag concept so I didn't even think of that - thanks so much.